# How do I convert an array of T (IEnumerable<T>) to IQueryable<T> for processing with LINQ?

Tags: wcf, linq, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, lightspeed

I'm working on an app using a WCF server (using the new beta Mindscape LightSpeed ORM) and consuming the service at an ASP.NET MVC2 client. My entities show up at the client as array of `T`, or `IEnumerable<T>`.  I want to do cool things with the data after it has arrived, but the LINQ syntax required `IQueryable<T>`.

I know there is a way to convert from `IEnumerable<T>` to `IQueryable<T>`, but I have had no luck so far searching for it.  Can anybody help?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Thanks for fixing my typo, Ani...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I suspect you're thinking of [`Queryable.AsQueryable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734.aspx) - but what makes you think that you need to use `IQueryable<T>` to use LINQ? Converting an `IEnumerable<T>` to `IQueryable<T>` won't give you most of the benefits of `IQueryable<T>`.

LINQ to Objects is all based around `IEnumerable<T>`. If you're happy working with the data you've already received, that's all you need.

If, however, you want to express a query at your client and tell the WCF server to execute that query (e.g. performing the filtering in the database or at least at the WCF side), *that's* when you'd use `IQueryable<T>`. You might find my [Edulinq post about `IQueryable<T>`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/20/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-43-out-of-process-queries-with-iqueryable.aspx) useful. You'd need some way of representing the service as an `IQueryable<T>` though - and at that point you're beyond my WCF knowledge.

Comment: Thanks Jon! That's what I was looking for.  I am implementing the PaginatedList helper class from the MVC NerdDinner example in my application, and it uses IQueryable<T> as the 'source' argument.  I hadn't thought about modifying the example code to use IEnumerable<T> in place of IQueryable<T>, but that might work just as well.

Comment: @DaveN59: I suspect it will, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method:
`AsQueryable()`